# Why does adding the material ui dropdown component to my react native app gives error TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine:

Tags: javascript, react-native, material-ui

After installing Material ui and importing The `Dropdown` component I get the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine: hermes`.

This is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { SelectList } from "react-native-dropdown-select-list";
import { Dropdown } from "react-native-material-dropdown";

export default function CelebrateButton() {
  let [count, setNum] = useState(0);
  let [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  let [data, setData] = useState([{ key: "0", value: "" }]);
  let [dur, setDur] = useState(0);

  const getCatagories = () => {
    return fetch("http://192.168.178.181:1880/api/getCatagories")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const c_name = json.map((obj) => obj.c_name);
        const c_duration = json.map((obj) => obj.c_duration);
        setData([...c_name]);
        console.log(c_duration);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const celebrate = async () => {
    let numberDur = parseInt(dur) * 1000;
    const data = {
      duration: numberDur,
    };

    fetch("http://192.168.178.181:1880/celebrate", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error:", error));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCatagories();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={celebratePage.container}>
      <Text>
        {count} {selected}
      </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button
        onPress={celebrate}
        title="Press"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        placeholder="Catagory duration"
        onChangeText={setDur}
      />
      <Dropdown
        label="Celebration category"
        data={data}
        containerStyle={celebratePage.container}
      />
      <SelectList
        setSelected={(val) => setSelected(val)}
        data={data}
        save="value"
        search={false}
        onPress={getCatagories}
      />
      <Text>{selected}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const celebratePage = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "fndemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "mysql2": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried reinstalling the packages but and deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it with `npm install` but it is still not working.

I tried adding the `style` property to the `Dropdown` component.

Comment: Looks like you cannot add `style` prop to `Dropdown`

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". The current title simply repeats the tags, which helps no one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry about that, I don't post questions that much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's an inconsistency between React Native avoiding use of propTypes and `react-native-material-*` using them.

You can fix that problem in the `Dropdrown` on the package.

Open the following file `node_modules/react-native-material-dropdown/src/components/dropdown/index.js`, then comment out the line with `itemTextStyle`:

```
-        itemTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
+        // itemTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
```

Additionally, apply a patch:

```bash
npx patch-package react-native-material-dropdown
```

If you are still facing issues then you may need to "fix" `TextButton` and `RaisedTextButton` commenting out `titleStyle` in their root files at `react-native-material-buttons`:

```
-    titleStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
+    // titleStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
```

Apply the patch:

```bash
npx patch-package react-native-material-dropdown react-native-material-buttons
```

I worked well for me!